# ProgressBar for a Huge List of INSERT - UPDATE Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

Solved I was only searching for VB.NET but i tried to search C# and i found a solution and just converted to VB.NET

Sorry and thanks for everyone!

I'm going to INSERT & UPDATE about 600 queries contains update and insert so I want to have a progressbar to show how long it will take for that this is the exp of the query I will be using :

```
Dim sqlTexts = {
"UPDATE " & Form3.WorkTableName.Text & " Set `stat_value1` = `stat_value1` " & USEMULTIPLE.Text & " " & Stamina.Text & " WHERE stat_type1 = 7;",
"UPDATE " & Form3.WorkTableName.Text & " Set `stat_value2` = `stat_value2` " & USEMULTIPLE.Text & " " & Stamina.Text & " WHERE stat_type2 = 7;",
"UPDATE " & Form3.WorkTableName.Text & " Set `stat_value3` = `stat_value3` " & USEMULTIPLE.Text & " " & Stamina.Text & " WHERE stat_type3 = 7;",
"UPDATE " & Form3.WorkTableName.Text & " Set `stat_value4` = `stat_value4` " & USEMULTIPLE.Text & " " & Stamina.Text & " WHERE stat_type4 = 7;",
"UPDATE " & Form3.WorkTableName.Text & " Set `stat_value5` = `stat_value5` " & USEMULTIPLE.Text & " " & Stamina.Text & " WHERE stat_type5 = 7;",
"UPDATE " & Form3.WorkTableName.Text & " Set `stat_value6` = `stat_value6` " & USEMULTIPLE.Text & " " & Stamina.Text & " WHERE stat_type6 = 7;",
"UPDATE " & Form3.WorkTableName.Text & " Set `stat_value7` = `stat_value7` " & USEMULTIPLE.Text & " " & Stamina.Text & " WHERE stat_type7 = 7;",
"UPDATE " & Form3.WorkTableName.Text & " Set `stat_value8` = `stat_value8` " & USEMULTIPLE.Text & " " & Stamina.Text & " WHERE stat_type8 = 7;",
"UPDATE " & Form3.WorkTableName.Text & " Set `stat_value9` = `stat_value9` " & USEMULTIPLE.Text & " " & Stamina.Text & " WHERE stat_type9 = 7;",
"UPDATE " & Form3.WorkTableName.Text & " SET `stat_value10` = `stat_value10` " & USEMULTIPLE.Text & " " & Stamina.Text & " WHERE stat_type10 = 7;"
}

        Using _
            conn As New MySqlConnection("server=" & Form2.hostname.Text & ";Port=" & Form2.portid.Text & "; user id=" & Form2.hostuser.Text & "; password=" & Form2.ascentpass.Text & ";SslMode = none; database=" & Form2.databasename.Text & ""),
            command As New MySqlCommand With {
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                .Connection = conn
            }
            conn.Open()
        For Each sql As String In sqlTexts
            Try
                ProgressBar1.Maximum = sql.Count
                For i As Integer = 0 To sql.Count - 1
                    command.CommandText = sql
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    If True Then
                        ProgressBar1.Value = i + 1
                    End If
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
        Next
    End Using
```

Comment: Congratulations.  What have you tried and where are you stuck?  Questions of the form *"I want to do X, tell me how"* are not valid here.  Your question needs to be of the form *"I want to do X, here's how I tried to do X and here's what happened when I tried it, please help me fix that issue"*.  Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) at least.

Comment: @jmcilhinney The main issue that i couldn't place progress bar anywhere to make it connect with the query long so that was the issue, i'm showing the SQL that needs the progressbar that's the far i could get..

Comment: Of course you could.  You just haven't bothered to do any research top find out how.  There are loads of examples of using `ProgressBar` controls already out there.  There's no need for us to write yet another one especially for you.  Make some effort on your own behalf and then we can help you with specific issues as you encounter them. This site is not intended as a place where you get taught the basics.

Comment: I've been searching for about 3 hours :D hehe okey i will try to add my failed attemps and thanks

Comment: @jmcilhinney Hey i've managed to solve it when i searched for C# answer i just converted to vb.net xD and it seems so easy i was doing it very complicated that's why didn't work for me sorry and thanks, anyway to mark this as solved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increment a variable on for each cicle after `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` and you you mast set a max value of progressbar at number of queries

```
Dim sqlTexts = {
"UPDATE " & Form3.WorkTableName.Text & " Set `stat_value1` = `stat_value1` " & USEMULTIPLE.Text & " " & Stamina.Text & " WHERE stat_type1 = 7;",
"UPDATE " & Form3.WorkTableName.Text & " Set `stat_value2` = `stat_value2` " & USEMULTIPLE.Text & " " & Stamina.Text & " WHERE stat_type2 = 7;",
"UPDATE " & Form3.WorkTableName.Text & " Set `stat_value3` = `stat_value3` " & USEMULTIPLE.Text & " " & Stamina.Text & " WHERE stat_type3 = 7;",
"UPDATE " & Form3.WorkTableName.Text & " Set `stat_value4` = `stat_value4` " & USEMULTIPLE.Text & " " & Stamina.Text & " WHERE stat_type4 = 7;",
"UPDATE " & Form3.WorkTableName.Text & " Set `stat_value5` = `stat_value5` " & USEMULTIPLE.Text & " " & Stamina.Text & " WHERE stat_type5 = 7;",
"UPDATE " & Form3.WorkTableName.Text & " Set `stat_value6` = `stat_value6` " & USEMULTIPLE.Text & " " & Stamina.Text & " WHERE stat_type6 = 7;",
"UPDATE " & Form3.WorkTableName.Text & " Set `stat_value7` = `stat_value7` " & USEMULTIPLE.Text & " " & Stamina.Text & " WHERE stat_type7 = 7;",
"UPDATE " & Form3.WorkTableName.Text & " Set `stat_value8` = `stat_value8` " & USEMULTIPLE.Text & " " & Stamina.Text & " WHERE stat_type8 = 7;",
"UPDATE " & Form3.WorkTableName.Text & " Set `stat_value9` = `stat_value9` " & USEMULTIPLE.Text & " " & Stamina.Text & " WHERE stat_type9 = 7;",
"UPDATE " & Form3.WorkTableName.Text & " SET `stat_value10` = `stat_value10` " & USEMULTIPLE.Text & " " & Stamina.Text & " WHERE stat_type10 = 7;"
}


 Dim ProgressBar1 As ProgressBar
 ProgressBar1.Location = New Point(10, 10)  
 ProgressBar1.Maximum = "getNumOfQuery()"



    Using _
    conn As New MySqlConnection("server=" & Form2.hostname.Text & ";Port=" & Form2.portid.Text & "; user id=" & Form2.hostuser.Text & "; password=" & Form2.ascentpass.Text & ";SslMode = none; database=" & Form2.databasename.Text & ""),
                command As New MySqlCommand With {
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                    .Connection = conn
                }
                conn.Open()
                For Each sql As String In sqlTexts
                    Try

                        command.CommandText = sql
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        ProgressBar1.Value=ProgressBar1.Value+1
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                    End Try
                Next
            End Using
```

Comment: A small exp on how this can be done, would be really thankful

Comment: This is not an answer.  Answers should be self-contained, not give vague indications of what to do.  That said, this question, as asked, doesn't warrant an answer because it doesn't involve a specific issue.

Comment: ProgressBar1.Location = New Point(10, 10) that's not necessary but it works too :) thanks